# How to determine whether Stripe webhook 'invoice.payment_failed' has been called from Stripe action or user action?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

I have a webhook for the Stripe event of `invoice.payment_failed`. This webhook is triggered whenever a customer payment fails for an invoice.

The webhook can be called multiple times per month if the user can insufficient funds for example.

My application allows a user to login to their account and initiate a manual attempt to pay the invoice if they have already had a failed payment attempt that month. It is initiated through the below call:

```
stripe.invoices.pay(invoiceId);
```

Docs: https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/pay

The above method also calls the `invoice.payment_failed` webhook. As far as I can tell, there are no ways of telling whether the webhook was initiated by a Stripe internal action (such as a payment retry), or a manual API action such as my call above.

I compared the event objects between the two types of calls and they are identical. Are there any other ways of determining what triggered the webhook?

Comment: I'm curious what the use case is here. Wondering if there's an internal counter that you keep track of as you receive webhooks, and if the user takes an action, you reset that counter...

Comment: @w1zeman1p - Almost! My app keeps count of the `invoice.payment_failed` webhook if it is called from a Stripe internal action. I do not want the count to be changed if the webhook if initiated by the user though.

Comment: @Fizzix did you ever find a viable solution for this issue? I am encountering the exact same issue. I would like to send an email to the user from the invoice.payment_failed webhook, but I don't want to do this if the user is manually paying the invoice when the card declines.

Answer (score 2):

Before calling `stripe.invoices.pay(invoiceId)`, you could add something to the `metadata` field to be able to identify the invoice later: https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/update#update_invoice-metadata

Comment: Not ideal as it requires a call to update the invoice's metadata before the API call, and then again to remove the metadata after identifying it within the webhook.

Answer (score 1):

After running into the same issue I have figured out how to differentiate `invoice.payment_failed` webhook events from manual vs automated attempts.

Take a look at the attempt_count field on the invoice object, this only increments on automated retries not on manual API calls e.g: `stripe.invoices.pay(invoiceId)`

https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-attempt_count

The way this works in my webhook endpoint is I look up the userRecord which contains a property `user.subscription.attemptCount` and I compare this to the attempt_count from the webhook payload.

Documentation for this property is as follows:

> Number of payment attempts made for this invoice, from the perspective
> of the payment retry schedule. Any payment attempt counts as the first
> attempt, and subsequently only automatic retries increment the attempt
> count. In other words, manual payment attempts after the first attempt
> do not affect the retry schedule.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to address this problem is to proxy the webhook requests that are initiated by the Stripe internal action. You can use a free webhook routing tool such as Pipedream (or equivalent) and append a field to the request.

First, create an endpoint to proxy the webhook

Second, handle the event:

```
{
      "id": "in_1DGXg2BSZsoltGfCP90zepqA",
      "object": "invoice",
      "account_country": "US",
      "account_name": null,
      "amount_due": 999,
....
```

Third, add an identifier Stripe internal action:

```
$event.body.identifier = 'internal_action'
```

And then route the data to the endpoint in your application.

Here is an example pipeline with this process working -- https://urlzs.com/nGd1a